# Switching mediaElements videos

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, video, media

I am working on a video project. In that project there will be a video playing for the user, and if the user clicks a button- that video is changed to the next one. Point is, the next video will play from the point the previous one stopped in (So if the user presses the NEXT button at 00:00:30 the next video will play from that point).

The problem I am facing is that there are always a few moments of black screen until the next video will play, and I want the change to be smooth without the user watching a black screen for a second or two.

So far,  I've tried to solve it with one mediaElement and with two mediaElements:

The single `mediaElement` change code:

```
TimeSpan Time = mediaElement1.Position;
mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("NEXT VIDEO LOCATION"); 
mediaElement1.Position = Time; 
mediaElement1.Play();
```

Two `mediaElement`s code:

```
TimeSpan Time = mediaElement1.Position;
mediaElement2.Source = new Uri("NEXT VIDEO LOCATION");
mediaElement2.Position = Time;
mediaElement1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
mediaElement1.Source = null;
mediaElement2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
mediaElement2.Play();
```

At both tries there is no smooth switch between the videos. Thanks in advance for any light on that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if I was not as clear as I would. In fact the `MediaElement` has the `Position` property but it is not a `DependancyProperty` and is not Bindable. There is also no way to retrieve the updated position with an event directly. So the way I used long time ago was the use of the MediaTimeLine in a StoryBoard. You should take a look on this post [How to: Control a MediaElement by Using a Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747245%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from Microsoft.
I used this way to seek in a video file using a MediaElement. The other way was the use of a third party library named WPFMediaKit which is very useful. You can find it there 
[WPF MediaKit - For webcam, DVD and custom video support in WPF](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/)

**FIRST EXAMPLE** : Using WPFMediaKit (no actual way to play MP4 files...)

The `MediaUriElement` in the WPF MediaKit allows you to bind its `MediaPosition` because it is a `DependancyProperty`. The `MediaUriElement` is a wrapper around the .Net `MediaElement` which is poor in functionnalities. So, refering to my first answer, I write a very simple POCO. You could write something like this :

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Media.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:media="clr-namespace:WPFMediaKit.DirectShow.Controls;assembly=WPFMediaKit"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="SwitchToSecondPlayerStoryboard">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="firstPlayer">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="secondPlayer">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="switchButton">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SwitchToSecondPlayerStoryboard}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <media:MediaUriElement x:Name="firstPlayer" Source="firstFile.wmv" LoadedBehavior="Play"/>
    <media:MediaUriElement x:Name="secondPlayer" Source="secondFile.wmv" MediaPosition="{Binding Path=MediaPosition, ElementName=firstPlayer}" Visibility="Collapsed" Volume="0"/>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="switchButton" Content="SWITCH NEXT FILE" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="OnSwitchButtonClick"/>
</Grid>
```

And here is the **MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Media
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnSwitchButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do whatever you want with the players.
        }
    }
}
```

This program works and there is no "blank screen" effect. You just have to improve the `Storyboard` transition (example with a FadeIn effect), but this is the principle. 
You would also note that the `MediaPosition` of the second is bound to the `MediaPosition` of the first one. 
This implies to always check that the `MediaPosition` is lower than the `Duration` of the file to avoid errors, but this is just code stuff.

*Note that I simplified my code avoiding the usage of MVVM and other architecture things in order to keep it clearer.*

**SECOND SOLUTION** : Workaround using `MediaElement`

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Media.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="ShowSecond">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="firstMediaElement">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="secondMediaElement">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="btnlaunchNext">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowSecond}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Background="Black">

            <MediaElement Name="firstMediaElement" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Source="firstFile.mp4" Width="260" Height="150" Stretch="Fill" />
            <MediaElement Name="secondMediaElement" Volume="0" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Source="secondFile.mp4" Visibility="Collapsed" Width="260" Height="150" Stretch="Fill" />

            <!-- Buttons to launch videos. -->
            <Button x:Name="btnlaunch" Content="PLAY FIRST" Click="OnLaunchFirstButtonClick"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnlaunchNext" Content="PLAY NEXT" Click="OnLaunchNextButtonClick"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Windows;

namespace Media
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for pour MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public TimeSpan Position { get; set; }

        Timer _updateTimer;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Timer interval fixed to 1 second to read the actual position of the first media element
            this._updateTimer = new Timer(1000);
            this._updateTimer.Elapsed += this.UpdateTimerElapsed;
        }

        //The callback of your update timer
        private void UpdateTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            //I use the dispatcher because you call the Position from another thread so it has to be synchronized
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.Position = firstMediaElement.Position));
        }

        //When stopping the first, you start the second and set its Position
        private void OnLaunchNextButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.firstMediaElement.Stop();

            this.secondMediaElement.Volume = 10;
            this.secondMediaElement.Play();
            this.secondMediaElement.Position = this.Position;
        }

        //When you start the first, you have to start the update timer
        private void OnLaunchFirstButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.firstMediaElement.Play();
            this._updateTimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

These are the only simple solutions I can provide. There are different ways to do this, particularly using `MediaTimeline`, but the implementation is not as easy as it seems, regarding the problem you are facing. The second example, as the first is fully compiling and running and targets what you wanted to do I think.

Hope this helps. Feel free to give me your feedback.

Comment: Thanks you for all the detailed answers. Sadly I don't quite understand how does the StoryBoard nor the MediaKit can help me achieve my requirements..

Comment: I just edited my post to code a little example of the usage of the WPFMediaKit. It works like you wanted to. Keep me informed.

Comment: I'm really sorry I'm bothering you so much but I can't get the MediaUriElement to work. I made a new project where I did add Reference to WPFMediaKit.dll and also the did the xmlns:media as you.My program only contains this line :  <media:MediaUriElement Name="firstPlayer" Source="FULL PATH OF A .MP4 FILE" LoadedBehavior="Play" /> . There are no compile errors, but when I run it it just doesn't play anything. Am I missing something? Never worked with DLL's before.. Thanks alot.

Comment: Ok so I understand. I had not all the elements. MediaUrielement is not able to read MP4 files. It only reads WMV files. So the only way to work with is to use WMV files. Are MP4 files a definitive choise ? I will try to find you something else if needed.

Comment: Yea, It must support .MP4's. If you can't find anything I will surely accept your answer. You helped plenty ! Thanks!

Comment: I wrote a second solution. It is a workaround using the `MediaElement`. It works like you wanted to I think. I tried a lot of solutions but the simplest is the last one with the `MediaElement` and the `Timer`. Hope this will solve your problem or help you finding the best way to implement a solution.

Comment: You've helped me so much. It works! Thank you again for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to preload the next video ? If it is the case, you could try to load both sources on each `MediaElement` and then bind the `Position` of the first to the second one while playing. 
The second `MediaElement` is `Collapsed` by default (preferable from `Hidden` regarding performance when using heavy graphical elements) and will become `visible` and its `Source` is already loaded and its `Position` already bound on the first `MediaElement` position.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do know what the next video will be so I can preload it. I am having problem binding the position as you mentioned, mind helping me with that? Thanks alot !

Comment: Did my new answer helped ? Feel free to ask some more if you need.